# How to display the particular ID image from the server folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The image filenames are stored by unique by add `vendorID` before with it like "200018hari". The below picture show the Table where the `filename` is stored in the column `Cmp_DocPath`.

[image: The Table where the filename is stored in the column Cmp_DocPath]

I want to display the particular `VendorID` image from the Server folder "D:\Upload\Commerical Certificates" when the user select the `vendorID` from the dropdownlist.(The picture will not show the full form design with the dropdownlist.)

[image: Form design]

I try this in Inline code but image not display. But I know this will not help me if the user select other `VendorID` from the dropdown.

How I will do by the code-behind in C# ?

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="400px" 
    ImageUrl ="AdminCompanyInfo.aspx?FileName=~/Upload/Commerical Certificates/200027mcp.png"/>
```

Comment: Sounds like a security issue to me if the client can define the path on the server where he wants to download something. (how about downloading your web.config then?)

Comment: The client just upload the image using File Upload.I am created the Virtual path in IIS and give path to store the uploaded image. So client not define the path of the server. I need C# code for retrieve the image from the folder to display in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the advice from my friends, I change the code for storing the image in the physical path "D:\Upload" and store the uploaded images in the "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\". Finally, create virtual directory in IIS and give the "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Upload" as physical path. The below C# code retrieve the image from the virtual path.

```
      private void CallImage()
      {
       SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
       SqlCon.Open();
       string query = "SELECT FilePath FROM CompanyInfo 
              WHERE VendorID= '" + ddlVendorID.SelectedValue + "'";
       SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, SqlCon);
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       da.Fill(dt);
       string ImageName = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
       Image1.ImageUrl = ("~\\Upload\\Commerical Certificates\\" + ImageName);
       SqlCon.Close();
     }
```

Comment: How do you secure the images from unauthorized access?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the image (`Cmp_DocPath`) that is associated with a `VendorID`, you need to use a `Generic Handler`. The following should be the technique of the `Generic Handler`.

1. That `Generic Handler` will read the image name from the database
2. after that it read the image file in to a binary array
3. after that it will write the array in response of the request.

That must work.

Comment: The `code formatting` style seems to be `very` popular `in` India, these `days`.

Comment: @UweKeim :: What did you mean?